# Complements of homeomorphic subsets of surfaces homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

Let us consider a surface $S$ and a subset $T\subset S$, where $T\cong D^2$ are homeomorphic and $D^2$ is an open disc.
Let $T\cong Q\subset S$ be homeomorphic.

Are $S\setminus T $ and $S\setminus Q$ homeomorphic?

If not, under which circumstances is it possible?

I think, if $T\subseteq Q$ and there exists an open $\epsilon$-neighbourhood around $Q$ which we call $U_\epsilon(Q) $, s.t. $U_\epsilon(Q)\cong D^2$, then $S\setminus Q\cong S\setminus T$.

Because: $U_\epsilon(Q)\setminus Q$ is homeomorphic to an annulus. But also $Q\setminus T$ should be homeomorphic to an annulus. But then the implication is clear.

In an analog way we see: If there exist an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood and $\delta $-neighbourhood around $T$ and $Q$ which we call $U_\epsilon(T)$ and $U_\delta (Q)$, s.t. they are homeomorphic to $D^2$, then $S\setminus Q\cong S\setminus T$.

But I can't imagine a way solving it without such neighbourhoods for a general surface. Maybe there is a way solving the problem for compact surfaces. But this is more intuition than real knowledge.

Comment: For points $x,y\in S$, define $x\sim y \iff (S\setminus \{x\}) \text{ is homeomorphic to } (S\setminus \{y\})$. It may not be obvious, but this is related to your question.

Comment: A solid disc is not homeomorphic to a point. I'm sorry but I don't really understand what you (@daniel) are applying on. Further more I forgot to mention that $D^2$ should be open.

Comment: Ah, if you remove open disks, it becomes more complicated, I thought one removes closed disks. And then, although a closed disk is evidently not homeomorphic to a point, $S\setminus D$ is homeomorphic to $S\setminus \{p\}$ for any point $p \in \overset{\Large\circ}{D}$.

Comment: If you use open discs this isn't true. The complement of a point in $S^2$ is homeomorphic to an open disc, but so is the complement of a closed disc.